I have the correct recovery key for Bitlocker but can't access the OS/Drive
I had one Windows on one hard drive and then installed a second windows on another drive. So I had two Windows two boot on one or another (both Windows 11) Then I Bitlocker the second drive directly from its Windows but when it did the first restart to verify the keys, the blue screen demands me the Bitlocker key but the key didn't work. I know the key is correct because the key ID is correct.
I tried going through the advanced recovery option and manage-bde, but it prompts that the key couldn't unlock the volume (also from the other Windows 11 through the terminal). I tried the key directly through the blue screen, and through the first drive Windows, and unplugging the SSD from the computer and plugging it again with a USB adapter, I tried also in another computer. When I tried through another Windows it prompts "key doesn't match with this unit". I tried writing it with the keyboard and through copy-pasting the code.

You have no recourse.  If the recovery key is not working then you cannot unlock the drive to access the data. I suspect you might have performed a shutdown of the system while the disk was being encrypted.

I checked the "restart before encryption for verify keys option", after the restart the blue screen demans me the key and after I wrote it, a death blue screen appeared with message error "unmountable boot device" (something like that)

What you describe is an unmountable encrypted boot device and is NOT BitLocker problem necessaryl.  Your question does not mention this fact and actually significantly changes what your problem is, I still don't think there is a solution, since I suspect the device is in an unrecoverable unbootable state.

That was only the first blue screen error, after that I can mount the device and tried the recovery key directly in the motherboard and through an USB adaptor.

Does not change the fact it sounds like the device is unbootable
